# Check if string is contained into another one

Tags: vba, loops

I have problems with one string and I would love to have some help.
Through iteration I get those htmlelement innertex:

31-12-2017

31-12-2016

31-12-2015
Etc.

I would like that one string inserted through inputbox will be searched in those elements, but the string contains only the year (for example 2017).
I tried to use instr and instrrev and in both case the string doesn't match even if there is.

This is part of my code:

```
Dim setdata as String
Dim datacheck as mshtml.ihtmlelement
Dim datachecks as mshtml.ihtmlelementCollection

Setdata = application.inputbox 'etc.

Datachecks = iedoc.getelementbyclassname("example") 'it finds all the date in the page (I checked through debug.print)'

For each datacheck in datachecks:
If instr(setdata, datacheck.innertext, vbtextcompare) then 'i also tried instrrev'
Debug.print "ok"
Else
Debug.print "no"
End if
Next datacheck
```

I always get no even if through inputbox I insert 2017 and the element collection.contains 31-12-2017.
Can you help me?

Comment: Check your variable names, at first u got Datachecks, later datachecks. It may have impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you mixing up the sequence. To me it seems your code is looking for "datacheck" in "setdata", while my understanding is that you are looking for "setdata" in "datacheck".

```
Dim a as String         'The string to look for
Dim b as String         'The string to look in
Dim c as Long

a = "A"
b = "aabb AbAb BAAb"

c = InStr(b,a)         'Function looking for the first occurrence of a in b
Print.Debug c          'This will give the value of 6, the location "A" first appears in string b.
```

BR
Fnk